# Cannot access my Wampserver thru global ip

Tags: apache, wamp

I need to access my wamp for a moment thru my global IP address. But I can't. I'm using the latest WAMP 2.5 for 32-bit.

It has worked before when I've had earlier versions of wamp. Just go to tray icon > Put Online and voila. Seems like they changed something.

Even if I put it online I cant access it. It says wamp is online.

I don't get any "access denied" which you used in earlier versions of wamp, it just keeps loading until timeout and then I get browser can't reach website error message. "This website is not available" google chrome.

I have DMZ set up on the comp so the ports are not a problem.

In httpd.conf I found this (this is default):

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/www/">
#
# Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
# or any combination of:
#   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
#
# Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
# doesn't give it to you.
#
# The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
# http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
# for more information.
#
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

#
# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
# It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
#   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
#
AllowOverride all

#
# Controls who can get stuff from this server.
#

#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: if the browser just spins for a while THEN says unreachable, then it's a network issue and your server's port 80 isn't reachable. trivial way to check: `tail -f` your access log, try to hit the server with your browser, and if you don't see the hit, there ya go - you're not even hitting the server.

Comment: To add to what Marb B said, visit the site via http://localhost and if it is available then you have a networking issue. The cause could be tenfold, a network appliance like a router or hardware firewall, or software related like an antivirus or windows firewall.

Comment: Ok this is embarassing. I just had to forward port 80. Never had to do that before I just put my local IP in dmz host. I should have tried that. Sorry for wasting database space admins